# Blazor state not updatting between child components when using events

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have two independent components in a Blazor wasm app between whichi am trying to communicate. under certain cases the communication fails and I cannot understand why.

The(simplified) setup is as follows

```
<ParentComponent>
    <HeaderComponent>
        <ProgressBar IsLoading="<Set by IsLoading property from header>" />
    </HeaderComponent>
    <ResultContainer />
</ParentComponent>
```

The code behind looks something like this:

```
public class ResultContainerStateManager
{
    public event Action OnLoadStart;

    public event Action OnLoadFinish;

    public NotifyLoadStart() => this.OnLoadStart?.Invoke();

    public NotifyLoadFinish() => this.OnLoadFinish?.Invoke();
}

public partial class HeaderComponent
{
    [Inject]
    public ResultContainerStateManager ResultContainerStateManager { get; set; }

    private bool IsLoading { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
          this.ResultContainerStateManager.OnLoadStart += () => this.IsLoading = true;

          this.ResultContainerStateManager.OnLoadFinish += () => this.IsLoading = false;

          base.OnInitializer();
    }
}

public partial class ResultContainer
{
    [Inject]
    public ResultContainerStateManager ResultContainerStateManager { get; set; }

    private bool IsLoading { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
          <code>

          if (shouldLoadData)
          {
               this.ResultContainerStateManager.NotifyLoadStart();

               <more code>

               this.ResultContainerStateManager.NotifyLoadFinish();
          }

          await base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
}

public partial class ProgressBar
{
     [Parameter]
     public bool IsLoading { get; set; }
}
```

Where the `IsLoading` parameter from the progress bar is set from the `IsLoading` property from `HeaderComponent`, like

```
<div id="headerComponent">
    
    <More html here>

    <ProgressBar IsLoading="@this.IsLoading" />
</div>
```

I don't think it matters, but the progress bar itself uses the `MatProgress` component, like so:

```
@if (this.IsLoading)
{
    <MatProgress Indeterminate="true" />
}
else 
{
    <Other html code>
}
```

The problem is that the progress bar starts when the `ResultContainer` executes the `NotifyLoadStart()` method, but it doesn't stop when the `NotifyLoadFinish()` method is executed.
I can see when debugging that the `IsLoading` property of the `HeaderComponent` is set back to false after the `NotifyLoadFinish()` call, but it has no Effect on the UI.

What I have tried so far:

- injecting the `ResultContainerStateManager` directly into the Progress bar
- I have tried changing the envents to Func and handling at all asynchronously
- I have tried adding `await Task.Yield()` after each `Notify` call
- I have tried adding `this.StateHasChanged()` calls in the event handlers and after each `Notify` call (I know the latter should not change anything at all, since it is not in the same hierarchy)

None of that changed anything and I would really like to understand why.

The only success I've had was when using `EventCallbacks` instead of the events. But I am using events in lots of other places and they all seem to work fine.

Could somebody tell me why events seem to fail and how this can be fixed?

Comment: The value of parameter ```IsLoading```  of the ```ProgressBar``` component is defined in what other component? What component "owns" it? Is it ```ParentComponent```, ```HeaderComponent``` or the page?

Comment: @Justthebenno it is in the `HeaderComponent`. The header passes it's own `IsLoading` property into the `ProgressBar`. i'll change the code to make that clearer.

Comment: I guess that base.OnInitializer() is a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
 public async Task OnLoadStart()
    {
        this.IsLoading = true;
        await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
    }



 public async Task OnLoadFinish()
    {
        this.IsLoading = false; 
        await InvokeAsync(() => { StateHasChanged(); });
    }

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
     this.ResultContainerStateManager.OnLoadStart += OnLoadStart;
     this.ResultContainerStateManager.OnLoadFinish += OnLoadFinish;
 }
```

Change : `public event Action OnLoadStart;`

To:       `public event Func<Task> OnLoadStart;`

And:   `public event Action OnLoadFinish;`

Tp:    `public event Func<Task> OnLoadFinish;`

Implement IDisposable in the HeaderComponent component:

```
@implements IDisposable

public void Dispose()
{
    this.ResultContainerStateManager.OnLoadStart -= OnLoadStart;
    this.ResultContainerStateManager.OnLoadFinish -= OnLoadFinish;
}
```

Start coding asynchronously wherever you can.

Comment: This works, thank you. It's the extra `this.StateHasChanged` in the `OnLoadFinish` that makes the diference. But I don't need it in the `OnLoadStart` method... I'd love to understand why. And also why it works perfectly sine without any `StateHasChanged` call when using `EventCallback`s. The whole thing is really ugly.

Comment: The reason for both is buried in the component life cycle. The method ```OnParametersSetAsync``` continues to render when it hits the first await. My guess is, that you invoke the method ```NotifyLoadStart()``` before any await? So the progress bar is rendered as expected. However, finishing is done later, so you need to invoke ```StateHasChanged()``` to trigger a rerender.  ```EventCallbacks``` on the other hand are "first part" blazor citizens. They trigger ```StateHasChanged()``` by themselves when they finished their action.

Comment: Using event Action as you did is fine. I've altered it (See my answer) to event Func<Task> so that you use asynchrony. Action is a delegate, and in the early days of Blazor we used it very often with UI event handler. Currently we shine from it, and use the EventCallback struct. Note that  EventCallback is not a delegate. Action is a delegate, Func is a delegate, but not EventCallback, which was specifically created for Blazor.

Comment: The EventCallback type provide the appropriate delegate to use. It especially determine and set the Target (This a property) of the Action delegate, and most importantly it automatically calls the StateHasCahnged method.